# Fragment и startActivityForResult

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Есть фрагмент с ImageView, хочу загрузить в этот ImageView фотку из галереи. Из активити работает без проблем, а из фрагмента не хочет. Подскажите в чем проблема?

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
    fp_imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, SELECTED_PICTURE);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.e(TAG,String.valueOf(resultCode));
    if (requestCode == SELECTED_PICTURE && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        uri = selectedImage.toString();
        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(uri).transform(new CircleTransform()).into(fp_imageView1);
    }

}
```

Фотка загружается и сразу же пропадает.

Comment: Попробуйте супер из резалта убрать

Comment: @ЮрийСПб пробовал - результат тот же! Решение то нашел, но оно из разряда "сохрани в преференсе, вытащи из активити", грабли.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ImageSelector extends Fragment{
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.createevent,container,false);

    imgcover = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.newcover_img);
    btnupload = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.newcover_upload);

    btnupload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
    }
    });
}

 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) 
    {
        Uri selectedImg = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImg,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        imgcover = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.newcover_img);
        imgcover .setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                cursor.close();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Дело в том, что так не работает. Мой код почти такой же, как и у вас! Различие только в том, что у вас на кнопке висит слушатель, а у меня на ImageView.